# JHipster ComboBox lazyloading

Tags: jhipster

I'm starter to use JHipster. One of my entity A has more than 3000 data. So I used infinite-scroll as pagination. But as relation to another Entry B, it will be generated as a comboBox in the dialog. I got only 20 data in the comboBox. There is no infinit-scroll or search and loading to get more data.

Can someone give any advice to fix the problem?

Comment: Can you eventually post some code? Add some more details?

Answer (score 1):

The infinite scroll uses pages (which is mapped to pageablea in spring). Thus, your service call that fetches the data for the box only fetches the first page. And the default page size is 20. So, you need to increase the page size to get more results.

You can either overwrite the "size" variable or the global constant called "itemsPerPage" which is located in `pagination.constants.js`

Am I right that it is a one-to-many relationshiop and you want to choose one of 3000 possible A for an entity B? 
If so, you don't want to load all 3000 possible As into the dropdown. Therefore, I would replace the dropdown with another input, e.g. the typeahead from angular-ui (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead), so you can fetch a filtered subset of your entities.

Another way, I also used before, would be a list with a pagination for A that opens in a modal and returns the selected entity that could be passed to b.

Or, if you really want to fetch all: I would add a new endpoint without the pageable, add a new method to the angular-resource-service and call this instead of the paged version.